# Camera Broken? All Images White...camera takes pictures but when I view them it it just a white screen

Tags: troubleshooting, digital, samsung

I have a Samsung NX3300 and had it for 3-4 years and  I've found a few answers but no ways to fix it (e.g., at [DP Review](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2632195) and [Tom's Guide](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2977846/camera-takes-pictures-view-white-screen.html)).

I can see it fine as I'm taking the image but if I view it in the gallery it is all white. Do I need to clean it; if so how?  Honestly, I have no clue how to even try to fix this. I tried to reset the settings and reattach the lens but nothing helped .

Comment: To reset the settings, what did you do?

Comment: What shooting mode are you using? (The dial on the top right of the camera)

Comment: Lighting conditions? Aperture, shutter speed, ISO?

Comment: It would probably help to give more detail about what you mean by "I can see it fine as I'm taking the image"? Could you [edit] your question to describe exactly what you see at each stage of taking the photograph? Does the camera display the photograph it has taken for a few seconds? If so, is that just plain white, or does it display a proper photograph then but save a white image to the card?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to check your camera settings. This could be something as simple as slipping the camera into manual mode and over exposing.

**Can you replicate the bright white with the lens fully covered by a lens cap?**

If yes then you have something electronically wrong with your camera and you need to call Samsung for service.

**Is the camera in automatic mode or manual mode?**

If the camera is in manual mode then try changing it to automatic mode.

**Can you use the video mode without the camera washing out?**

If these are fine then it could be a physical shutter issue, in which case I'd recommend calling Samsung's support number.

Comment: I'm not sure Samsung still supports the defunct NX series of ILCs?

Answer (score 0):

The NX3300 is a mirrorless camera, so there is a bit less potential for confusion than with a DSLR.  A DSLR tends to have a depth-of-focus preview mode that closes down the aperture to the value that is going to be used in the photograph.  A DSLR, however, does not reflect the chosen ISO value or the shutter speed in what you get to see in the viewfinder.

A mirrorless camera reflects those in "preview" mode while it does not do so in "framing" mode.  How those options are accessible with buttons or in menus differs between cameras and I am currently too lazy to search the online manuals for the information corresponding to the NX3300.

"framing" mode picks viewfinder exposure values (ISO and exposure time) that make it possible for you to see what you are pointing your camera at.  It doesn't guarantee that the picture will look anything like that.

In particular, it will not reflect over- or underexposure.  I think that may be what is happening here to you: you are overexposing, for whatever reasons.  Are you using "manual" mode or external flash?